# Windows 8 - can't drag files from Explorer and drop on applications

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8, drag-and-drop, user-experience

In Windows 8 I find I can't drag files to applications like I've been able to do for as long as I can remember. Example:

- Drag MP3s to Winamp
- Drag folder full of music to Winamp
- Drag videos to VLC
- Drag txt, reg etc files to Notepad

I have tried various combinations of:

- Running Explorer as administrator
- Running drop target as administrator
- Taking ownership of drop target application's folder
- Taking ownership of Explorer
- Changing user account to administrator
- Create a new user account
- Lowering UAC level
- Disabling UAC in GUI
- Disabling UAC in registry
- Running Explorer folders in a separate thread

This is the last straw if there's no known proper (ie non hacky compromise) fix for this. "Little" things like this combined are a productivity nightmare and if I have to relearn so much and configure so much to get basic things done with an OS I might as well just move to Linux once and for all.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you - I'm running Windows 8 RTM and was able just now to drag and drop an audio file onto VLC (I started VLC first, it was just sitting there) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: It occasionally works for me but usually I just get a "no entry" icon when I try.

Comment: I just went back and tried it, dragged about 8 different .mp4 files onto it. When you try it, does the icon change when you're holding the file over VLC?

Comment: Yep, the icon changes to a circle with a line through it like a no entry sign.

Comment: Is your `ESC` key struck. Try tapping it and then dragging and dropping. http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/15038-i-cant-drag-drop.html

Comment: Are you dragging files onto the Taskbar application icons?

Comment: [This](http://rprabu1984.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/drag-and-drop-not-working-in-windows-8/) solved it for me. Very happy and without messing with admin accounts or the UAC (as other solutions propose), this seems to be more clear and effective.

Comment: I got here trying to drag media files from my **smartphone internal storage** directly to VLC.  It only looks like any other folder, but apparently can't be used in this way.  Double clicking opens a new VLC window and plays properly, but dragging and dropping will not reuse an existing window to play a different file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, finally worked out what it is.
Any applications opened directly from Explorer seem to be fine.
Any applications opened from an application launcher anywhere in their history (eg: Launchy, Classic Shell start menu etc) exhibit the above behaviour.
Running the application launcher as Administrator mostly fixes the problem, though it still occurs infrequently and I still can't work out why.

Comment: Well, you worked how to solve it in most cases, but I personally have no idea about what it is. Anyway, I don't need to know that, but I'm very interested in knowing how can I run the application launcher as administrator. ;) Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, I did [this](http://rprabu1984.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/drag-and-drop-not-working-in-windows-8/) seems to be working now...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the applications cannot hook into explorer.

Try to refresh the PC, which takes 5 minutes(don't forget to back up of course) and if that does not work reinstall. I know it is a sucky solution but it definitely is a software problem specific to you.